# Can I write a optimization problem in this form?

Tags: optimization

The optimization problem looks like this now:

$minimize\;\frac{1}{N}\sum_{s=1}^N max\{L-Br_s^Tx,0\}$

$s.t.\;\sum_i x_i=1$

$x\ge0$

Is it ok to put the max part inside the objective function? If not, how should I correct it?

Answer (score 2):

Since each $\max(L - Br_s^Tx, 0)$ is not differentiable, we can add an extra variable $t_s$ equal to $\max(L - Br_s^Tx, 0)$:
$\min \frac{1}{N}\sum t_s$
s.t. $\sum x_i = 1$
$x \geq 0$
$L - Br_s^Tx \leq t_s$, $\forall r_s$
$0 \leq t_s$, $\forall r_s$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Then you can use a Linear Programming solver to numerically solve this.

Answer (score 0):

To make your problem differentiable, you can replace this kind of problem
$\min \max(a, b)$
with the smooth reformulation:
$\min t$
s.t.
$a \leq t$
$b \leq t$

Comment: Do you mean like this: minimize 1/N*sum(sf), s.t. L-B*r'*x <= sf, 0 <= sf, sum(x)=1, x>=0?

Comment: You need an extra variable for each $r_s$.

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. Could you please explain more? Thank you!